# How do we check equality of two Objects i.e. file contents in repository by using CommitIds?

Tags: git, egit, jgit

I have a scenario where I need to check the contents of the two files are equal or not.
What I have is the commitIds of both the files for the JGIT repository.

Is there any possibility  to check the equality using commitIds of the (files)Objects without exactly comparing the contents at all.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`RevObjectTest.java`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevObjectTest.java#L63-L89) test class:

```
assertTrue(AnyObjectId.equals(a1, a2));
assertTrue(AnyObjectId.equals(b1, b2));
```

If you have two ObjectID of the two files, you can use the [`org.eclipse.jgit.lib.AnyObjectId`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/AnyObjectId.java) util class to compare the SHA1.
If the SHA1 matches, the content of the files matches, since the SHA1 is a hash on the contents.

To find the ObjectId of a specific file, follow [ReadFileFromCommit.java](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/api/ReadFileFromCommit.java) from the excellent [JGit cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook), written by [centic9 (Dominik Stadler)](https://github.com/centic9) (also a [Stack Overflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411846/centic)):

```java
ObjectId lastCommitId = repository.resolve(Constants.HEAD);

// a RevWalk allows to walk over commits based on some filtering that is defined
RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(repository);
RevCommit commit = revWalk.parseCommit(lastCommitId);
// and using commit's tree find the path
RevTree tree = commit.getTree();
System.out.println("Having tree: " + tree);

// now try to find a specific file
TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(repository);
treeWalk.addTree(tree);
treeWalk.setRecursive(true);
treeWalk.setFilter(PathFilter.create("README.md"));
if (!treeWalk.next()) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("Did not find expected file 'README.md'");
}

ObjectId objectId = treeWalk.getObjectId(0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help VonC. Its working nicely. thank you so much